# Is compiling Polymer.js project to .js files possible?

Tags: javascript, gulp, polymer, polymer-1.0

I've got a polymer.js 1.x project that I want to bundle to optimize for production use.

- My project has several custom elements in /elements directory and lots (~100) dependencies in bower_elements.
- It does **not** use service worker and doesn't have manifest.json file.

I tried following directions published on https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/toolbox/build-for-production#bundling (the directions are on v2 documentation but there is info it would work for v1 projects too - tried it with polymer-starter-kit and it worked - files were bundled).

The build produces minified html,js,css files but I cannot get it to bundle my code, despite having set `bundle: true` in polymer.json `build` section.

My polymer.json contents:

```
{
  "entrypoint": "index.html",
  "fragments": [
    "elements/**/*"
  ],
  "sources": [
    "images/**/*",
    "bower.json",
    "index.html",
    "elements/**/*",
    "styles/**/*"
  ],
  "extraDependencies": [
    "bower_components/webcomponentsjs/*.js",
    "bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"
  ],
  "builds": [
    {
      "name": "es6-bundled",
      "js": {
        "minify": true,
        "compile": false
      },
      "css": {
        "minify": true
      },
      "html": {
        "minify": true
      },
      "bundle": true,
      "addServiceWorker": false,
      "addPushManifest": false,
      "preset": "es6-bundled"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Remove "preset": "es6-bundled" and check if it works?

Comment: @Ofisora Nope, unfortunately it didn't change anything :(

Comment: I saw that you are using polymer 1. Can you try bundled: true?